# finding projection on subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthonormal

I have a question:

> Find the projection of $v = <1,2,1>$ on $span(<3,1,2>,<1,0,1>)$ in
>   $R^3$

calling the vectors in the  span a and b
$$proj_w V = \frac{V \cdot a }{a^2} \vec{a} + \frac{V \cdot b }{b^2} \vec{b}$$

I've checked my work a few times.. $<\frac{5}{2} , \frac{1}{2}, 2>$ which isn't right via back of the book. I also think you can check via $V - proj_w V$ being orthogonal to all the vectors in the set.. which it is not.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A projection $P$ must satisfy $P^2=P$. That is whatever the vector which is on the projection space remains invariant under projection. Obviously $v=a$ or $v=b$ are counterexamples. To find the projection of $v$ on subspace, one should find an **orthogonal** basis of the space and then apply the formula you did.